# fire onclick event after jsf validation phase is successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I want to show the processing spinner in my website. I am using following simple onclick event on commandbutton

```
<h:commandButton class="uploadButton"  onclick="monitor();" value="Upload" update="msgsuccess" action="#{appUploadBean.uploadApp()}"/>


<p:outputPanel id="parentPanel" style="display:none">
                                   <div id="uploadPForm:msgupload" class="ui-messages ui-widget" aria-live="polite" data-summary="data-summary" data-severity="info">
                                      <div class="ui-messages-info ui-corner-all">
                                         <a href="#" class="ui-messages-close" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp();return false;">
                                            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" />
                                         </a>
                                        <h:graphicImage id="image" library="assets" name="images/ajax-loader.gif"></h:graphicImage> 
                                         <ul>
                                            <li>
                                               <span class="ui-messages-info-summary">Uploading Apk</span>
                                            </li>
                                         </ul>
                                      </div>
                                   </div>
                                 </p:outputPanel>  

--javascript

    function monitor(){
                console.log("monitor called");
                var loading = document.getElementById("uploadPForm:parentPanel");
                loading.style.display = "block";
                return false;           
            }
```

Now the problem is spinner starts displaying as soon as i click the command button. I want to show the spinner only after validation phase is successful i.e after phase 3..

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you use rendered? Which will be based on some property in backing bean which will be set to true after validation and you will update this outputPanel via ajax?

Comment: Can you give me the example here? control comes in the backing bean in phase 5..how can we set the flag after validation? Also how to fire ajax after validation..i am a newbie to jsf..

Answer (score 0):

in backing bean AppUploadBean you will have property:

Bean must be ViewScoped (prefered) or SessionScoped

```
private boolean rendered;

public String uploadApp(){
...
rendered = true;
return "actualpage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}

public boolean isRendered(){
return rendered
}
```

in xhtml:

```
<h:form>
...

    <p:commandButton class="uploadButton" value="Upload" update="msgsuccess" ajax="false" action="#{appUploadBean.uploadApp}"/>

    <p:outputPanel id="parentPanel" rendered="#{appUploadBean.rendered}">
    ...
    </p:outputPanel> 

...
</h:form>
```

Comment: Actually i am doing upload file on submit, and i was going through the online articles that file upload doesn't work on ajax call... so i guess i will have to stick with h:commandbutton

Comment: Tried the above code, but getting NullPointerException for file object since file didn't go through

Comment: @mihirS I modify my answer a bit. Now its not ajax based.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but here in the modifed code, spinner gets displayed after the processing of uploadApp function, i want to display the spinner as soon as control enter in phase 5...here the spinner appears after the app is uploaded...

Comment: I think it's not possible to render anything before [JSF render phase](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaqq.html) in lifecycle ... You can manage the lifecycle in phase listener but still I dont think so that you will achive behaviour what you want. And in my point of view its not standard user expected behaviour. Maybe you should describe what you want to achieve more precisely.

Comment: Basically i have a application upload form which has the inputs filed like app name, app package, file upload etc. All the fields in the for are mandatory. Now when someone clicks on upload after giving valid input in all the fileds i want to show the spinner with message as 'uploding Apk', Now with my current code of onclick, if someone clicks on upload button without filling some/all mandatory field, for few initial seconds uploading apk spinner will come and then the error of please enter 'mandatory filed come'.

Comment: The desired output here is, if there were validation error, i don't want that 'uploading apk' spinner, only if validations have passed, i want to start displaying the spinner